# Switching user in Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have a problem when using Fabric to mimic my SSH workflow to deploy my web application.

Here's my usual flow of commands when I SSH to a server:

1. SSH using root user.       ssh root@1.2.3.4
2. Switch to web user:        su - web
3. Change directory:          cd /srv/web/prod/abc_project
4. Start virtualenv:          workon abc_env
5. Perform git pull:          git pull origin master
6. Run a script:              build_stuff -m build
7. Run another script:        ./run

I tried to write this as a deploy script in Fabric and I get a shell output when su - web is entered.  I have to hit Ctrl-D to continue the script. I am also unable to activate my virtualenv....because:  su - web successfully switches the user to `web` but because of the Ctrl-d (so that I can continue the Fabric script), it logs out of that user and back to root.

Here's my script:

```
env.user = 'root'

@roles('web')
def deploy():
    dev_path = '/srv/web/prod'
    app_path = '/srv/web/prod/rhino'
    workon = 'workon rhino_env'
    with prefix('su - web'):
        puts('Switched to `web` user')
        with settings(warn_only=True):
            run('kill -9 `cat /srv/web/run/rhino/rhino.pid`')
            puts('Stopped rhino...')
        with cd(app_path):
            run('git reset --hard HEAD')
            puts('Discarded all untracked and modified files')
            run('git checkout master')
            run('git pull origin master')
            users = run('users')
            puts('Output from `users` command: %s' % users)
            run(workon)
            run('build_assets -m build')
        run('cd %(dev_path)s; chown -R web:ebalu rhino' % {'dev_path': dev_path})
        run('cd %(app_path)s; ./run' % {'app_path': app_path})
        pid = run('cat /srv/web/run/rhino/rhino.pid')
        puts('Rhino started again with pid: %s.' % pid)
```

...there's one more thing:  No, I can't login as web initially, I have to login as root.  It is the web user that has the virtualenv not the root user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you should use `sudo` when executing commands under another user. Second, `workon` sets environment variables for current shell. Since fabric invokes new shell for every command, you should run `workon rhino_env` in every command, where you need virtualenv (i.e. as prefix). With this edits yor code should look like this:

```
env.user = 'root'

@roles('web')
def deploy():
    dev_path = '/srv/web/prod'
    app_path = '/srv/web/prod/rhino'
    workon = 'workon rhino_env; '
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run('kill -9 `cat /srv/web/run/rhino/rhino.pid`')
        puts('Stopped rhino...')
    with cd(app_path):
        sudo('git reset --hard HEAD', user='web')
        puts('Discarded all untracked and modified files')
        sudo('git checkout master', user='web')
        sudo('git pull origin master', user='web')
        users = run('users')
        puts('Output from `users` command: %s' % users)

        with prefix(workon):
            sudo('build_assets -m build', user='web')
    with cd(dev_path):
        run('chown -R web:ebalu rhino')

    with cd(app_path):
        sudo('./run', user='web')

    pid = run('cat /srv/web/run/rhino/rhino.pid')
    puts('Rhino started again with pid: %s.' % pid)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I never thought of running git commands using the web user.  I kept trying to use `su - web` in front of the git commands instead.  Thanks a million mechmind!

Answer (score 4):

The way I achieve this is with

```
from fabric.api import settings

with settings(user='otheruser'):
    ...
```

You will be prompted for the password of `otheruser`, though only once. So it is not equivalent so `sudo su otheruser`, where root logs in to the user account without a password, but is is a simple way to switch between users in your script, only typing each password once

Comment: I swear this worked once! My provisioning task is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use the [sudo](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12.1/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo) operation instead of changing the remote user with `su`.