# Running fabric scripts as root

Tags: python, sudo, fabric, su

I am trying to use fabric to automate some administrative work that I am doing on a couple of servers. The general flow is the following:

1. SSH with local user
2. run: `sudo su -` to become root (providing local user password again)
3. Do the work as root :)

Unfortunately using `run('sudo su -')` blocks execution of the scripts and allows user input. When I type `exit` or `Ctrl+D` the scipt resumes, but without root privileges.

I have seen a similar problem in [Switching user in Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080643/switching-user-in-fabric) but I am restricted to `sudo su -` because I am not allowed to change the `/etc/sudoers` file which contains the following line:

`localuser ALL = /usr/bin/su -`

I browsed the source of fabric trying to find a workaround but with no success.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/env.html#sudo-prefix and this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641514/switch-to-different-user-using-fabric

Comment: Using `sudo_prefix='su - -c '` as described in that post requires the root password. If I use `sudo_prefix='sudo su - -c '` I get this error message `Sorry, user localuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/su - -c /bin/bash -l -c pwd' as root on hostname.`

Comment: Setting `shell=False` seems to have no effect. Setting `pty=False` returns the error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Answer (score 4):

Having faced the same problem as yours, (only `sudo su - user` allowed by admin, `sudo -u user -c cmd` not allowed), here's my working solution with `fabric`:

```
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run 

def sudosu(user, cmd):
    cmd += ' ;exit'
    prompts = []
    prompts += expect('bash', cmd)
    prompts += expect('assword:', env.password)

    with expecting(prompts):
        run('sudo su - ' + user)

def host_type():
    sudosu('root', 'uname -s')
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but it requires python to be on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions for your issue. First, you want to run commands using `sudo`. You can use the fabric method `sudo` instead of `run` that `runs a shell command on a remote host, with superuser privileges`([sudo ref](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/api/core/operations.html?highlight=sudo#fabric.operations.sudo)).

For example, these commands are executed using `sudo` :

```
sudo("~/install_script.py")
sudo("mkdir /var/www/new_docroot", user="www-data")
sudo("ls /home/jdoe", user=1001)
result = sudo("ls /tmp/")
```

Another idea is that you want to wrap a set of commands (that need to be `sudo`ed).
You can use Fabric context managers ([ref](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/api/core/context_managers.html?highlight=cd#fabric.context_managers.cd)) to do that. Particularly, you can use `prefix` or `settings`.

For example:

```
with settings(user='root'):
    run('do something')
    run('do another thing')
```

will ask you once the root password then execute commands as root.
You can tweek settings to store the password.

Comment: Both the solutions do not work for me. I have tried the first one and the `sudo('pwd')` translates to `sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "pwd"` and I get an error message `Sorry, user localuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -l -c pwd' as root on hostname.` The second solutions implies that I have the root password which I don't.

Comment: For the second solution, cant you use the password you would use normally to get superuser access?

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution for the following problem `Sorry, user localuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/su - -c /bin/bash -l -c pwd' as root on hostname.`
You can try `sudo('mkdir ~/test_fabric',shell=False)`. Using param `shell` to avoid the bash param `-l`.